# How to find hibernate orm or hibernate ogm use to connect for my mongodb server in spring boot

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-ogm

hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider** for connect mongodb to my spring boot application.I use JPA for my repositories. I cannot change jpa repositories because I previously use MySQL for project... I want to switch to mongodb... So I use **hibernate-ogm-mongodb** libarary for fulfill my requirment.

In SQL configuration I used below application.yaml

```
spring:
  main:
    web-environment: true
    banner-mode: console
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
  application:
    name: tportal
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/trade_portal_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false
    username: ****
    password: ****
```

But when I use hibernate ogm I confiused lot because how can i use **org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider** for application.yaml .... I added MongoDBDatastoreProvider property like this

```
spring:
  main:
    web-environment: true
    banner-mode: console

  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect  
    hibernate:
       ogm: 
         datastore:
              provider: org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider
              host: http://127.0.0.1/
              port: 27017
              grid_dialect: org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.mongodb.MongoDBDialect
              database: trade_portal_db
              create_database: true

  application:
    name: tradeportal
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: net.sf.mongodb_jdbc_driver.MongoDbDriver
    url: jdbc:mongo://127.0.0.1:27017/trade_portal_db
```

I want to know is the **JPA property need when configuration application.yaml** and **Which dialect should I use**... Otherwise I want to know is the *net.sf.mongodb_jdbc_driver.MongoDbDriver-* need when I use **org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider** driver..? **When I run the application it works fine.But I think it use hibernate orm**The console gives an error when I try to push logging button...

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:252) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:52) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:627) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1945) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1898) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:529) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:372) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3689.getSingleResult(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:206) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:85) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3675.getUserByLoginUserName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at lk.tradeportal.security.services.AuthenticationService.loadUserByUsername(AuthenticationService.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:114) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
```

How can I intergrate with JPA...

I read many of articles and try to connect mongodb to my spring boot application in many weeks ago... But I can't do that... Please help me someone...

This is my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--handle servlet-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--<Email Dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>      
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--jasper-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web-services -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ws.security/wss4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-libs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-libs</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.mongojdbcdriver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongojdbcdriver</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You have at least 4 other questions here asking the same thing. You are not supposed to keep repeating the same question here. if you have additional information to add to an existing question, then edit that instead of posting a variation on what is still the same question.

Comment: @NeilLunn I read many of the articles in stackoverflow... But I can't apply to my project... I'm newer for Java and Mongodb world.Please if u can help me....

Comment: "New" or not. You cannot keep posting the same question. I'm putting a hold on this and all other copies of the same question which don't yet have answers on them. Talk to the people who are already trying to answer you and explain to them what works or does not. No more posting the same question please.